# What is xml format/schema for shared preferences in Android?

Tags: android

Below is how `SharedPreferences` are read from a file, but what is xml format/schema for `SharedPreferences` file? How is it different from format for regular preferences? where is this schema posted? And which directory should the file reside in?

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: in preferences.xml for regular preferences PreferenceScreen is an element this does not seem right for shared preferences

Comment: I do not see a description of this schema is android docs. All examples show how to set values in code. I am looking for how to initialize the shared preferences from a file. In order to do that I need to know the format of the xml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a formal schema.  You can infer the format by looking at what it outpus though.  Open up DDMS in Eclipse, and browse to `/data/data/<your package>/shared_prefs`.  For example, you'll find:

```
<map>
  <int name="id" value="1" />
  <string name="first">John</string>
</map>
```

You might want to consider reading in your initialization values and using the SharedPreferences API to persist them.  This way, you can be sure that SharedPreferences will write it's file in the correct place.

Comment: +1 for "You might want to consider reading in your initialization values and using the SharedPreferences API to persist them." -- this will be much more reliable.

Comment: Ok. are there any conventions about where such a file would be placed under res? or I suppose one could reuse strings.xml file to read the values from ....

Comment: The non-standard way this is treated makes a sqlite a bit more attractive at this point than it was before.

Comment: If you need to persist individual values, then SharedPreferences is the way to go.  If you have need to persist a lot of data that is similar, then SQLite is the better choice.